# How do I push down control

Tags: c#, winforms, label, vertical-alignment

I have a label with variable-length text and a progressBar below to it. I want to keep a space between that label and the progressBar, so depending to label's text(which is wrapped) the progressBar should be pushed down, always keeping the space between them. How should I do that? I tried `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink` but it didn't changed anything. Example:

```
 ---------------------------
|  for example the label's  |
|  text might be something  |
|  like this, with a lot of |
|  of text but the progress |
|  bar should be here       |
|                           |
| progressBar here          |
 ---------------------------
```

example 2:

```
 ---------------------------
|  small text               |
|                           |
| progressBar here          |
 ---------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the Label and the ProgressBar into a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) that has its `FlowDirection` property set to `TopDown`.  Now when the Label grows vertically the ProgressBar will be pushed down automatically.  To control the distance between the Label and the ProgressBar, change the `Bottom` value in the `Padding` property of the Label.

Here's what my form looks like after hitting the button a couple times with `AutoSize` set to `true` on the Form and the FlowLayoutPanel (using `GrowOnly` in `AutoSizeMode`):

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i < 20; i++)
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text + " more ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, was not aware Winforms had a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: I can't reproduce it here. Here's my form http://oi60.tinypic.com/xoqdmq.jpg and then after hitting the button two times my form looks like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/v49i52.jpg `FlowDirection = TopDown` and Form's `AutoSize = true`. What am I missing?

Comment: Also `GrowOnly = AutoSizeMode` but it's default.

Comment: @Jack You need AutoSize set to true on both the FlowLayoutPanel and the Form

Comment: I'm trying to implement this again. But the text isn't growing properly... how do I fix this? http://prntscr.com/6oe9gj

Comment: AutoSize is set to true on both FlowLayoutPanel and the From also FlowDirection = TopDown

Answer (score 2):

If you save the initial `Y` position of your progressbar, you can set dynamically the location later according to your label's height. It will keep the padding you've set originally.

So if I have the following form, where the label is updated automatically on the button press, I can update the progress bar location in the button click event.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly int initialProgressbarLocationY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.MaximumSize = new Size(80, 1000); //Wrapping label
        label1.AutoSize = true;

        initialProgressbarLocationY = progressBar1.Location.Y; //Save the original position
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += "bla blablablabla bla";
        MoveProgressbar();
    }

    private void MoveProgressbar()
    {
        // Set the progressbar at the same X, but update the Y according to the label's height
        progressBar1.Location = new Point(progressBar1.Location.X,
            initialProgressbarLocationY + label1.Height);
    }
}
```

Which gives the following result after a few button clicks:

[image]

If your label starts with some text, you may need to subtract the original label height from the new Y or the padding will slightly increase the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Set your label.text. then

```
progessBar.Top = label.Bottom + WhateverSpaceYouWant
```