# Push down control automatically not working

Tags: c#, winforms, label, autosize

Sometime ago I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055744/how-do-i-push-down-control) question. I get an answer and it worked fine at time. But now, I'm trying to do the same but isn't working. I have a `Form` and a `FlowLayoutPanel` setted in the same way as the answer but it isn't working. Both `Form` has `FLowLayoutPanel` has set `AutoSize` to true and `FlowDirection` set to `TopDown` but the form is growing vertically without pushing down the `progressBar` control and `label` itself. Here's what's like my form after click on button a couple of times(the button's code is the same as in the accepted question in the link I have linked):

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works!

```
public Form1()
{
            InitializeComponent();

            Size = new Size(400, 150);
            AutoSize = true;
            AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;

            FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            panel.Size = new Size(200, 150);
            panel.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(panel.Width, int.MaxValue);
            panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            panel.AutoSize = true;
            panel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
            Controls.Add(panel);

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Starting text!\n";
            label.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 50);
            label.AutoSize = true;
            panel.Controls.Add(label);

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
            progressBar.Location = new Point(0, 125);
            progressBar.Size = new Size(190, 25);
            panel.Controls.Add(progressBar);

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(275, 50);
            button.Text = "Click me!";
            button.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { label.Text += "some more text, "; };
            Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: This line made it work `panel.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(panel.Width, int.MaxValue);` thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad that I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tested the solution suggested in the earlier post you made and it's working fine for me...
Test these things:

1. Make sure both the Label and the ProgressBar are located inside the FlowLayoutPanel
2. If you mean that it's growing horizontally <---->, then set the MaximumSize-Width of the FlowLayoutPanel to how wide it can be before switching to a new row (and from there growing vertically instead!)
3. Otherwise please provide more information so that I can help you from there.

Comment: Would you send me(upload somewhere and share the link here) the working project that you've tested? I got it working back then when I accepted the answer but now for some reason it isn't working for me anymore. No idea what changed.